# #pragma init and #pragma fini using gcc compiler on linux

Tags: c, gcc, pragma

I would like to build some code which calls some code on loadup of the shared library. I thought i would do it like this:

```
#pragma init(my_init)

static void my_init () {  
  //do-something
}

int add (int a,int b) {  
  return a+b; 
}
```

So when i build that code with

> gcc -fPIC -g -c -Wall tt.c

It returns

```
gcc -fPIC -g -c -Wall tt.c 
tt.c:2: warning: ignoring #pragma init 
tt.c:4: warning: ‘my_init’ defined but not used
```

So its ignoring my #pragmas. I tried this in real code and my code aborted because a function hadn't been called in the pragma section because it was ignored.

How do i get gcc to use these #pragma init and fini statements?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

pragmas are almost all compiler-specific.  GCC doesn't implement `init`, but you can get the same effect using the `constructor` function attribute:

```
static __attribute__((constructor)) void my_init()
{  
  //do-something
}
```

There's also a corresponding `destructor` attribute.

Comment: Hm, for gcc 4.4.6 I get a `expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token` error with the above example. When I remove the attribute from the function definition and put a function declaration with constructor attribute before it, it works as expected/[documented](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html).

Comment: @maxschlepzig: The attribute needs to be before the declarator in a function definition, updated.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently `#pragma init` and `#pragma fini` are only supported by GCC for Solaris:

- http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.3/gcc/Solaris-Pragmas.html#Solaris-Pragmas

Answer (score -3):

Instead, use C++:

```
// init.cpp
namespace // an anonymous namespace
{
     class autoinit
     {
         public:
             ~autoinit(){ /* destruction code, if applicable */ }
         private:
             autoinit(){ /* content of myinit */ }
             static autoinit _instance;
     };

     autoinit 
     autoinit::_instance; // static instance forces static construction
}
```

Comment: He may require his code to be called before any static constructors are called in which case this may not work (initialization order can't be controlled and is not guaranteed) and is pretty much impossible to actually do in standard c++.

Comment: @Grant, can you control the relative order of function declared with __attribute__((constructor))? If not, how is it any different? Besides, this method is portable across all C++ implementations, whereas the __attribute__((constructor)) syntax is GCC only.

Comment: I believe the __attribute__((constructor)) syntax does guarantee that it is called before all other code. Additionally, it allows you to specify a priority for that constructor so if multiple are specified it knows what order to run them in. As to the portability, I was saying that having your code called before any static class constructors (i.e. controlling initialization) isn't possible via standard c++, there is no portable way of doing it. You have simply pointed out what I was saying already and your method still doesn't allow for the code to run before any static classes.

Comment: @Grant Peters - Just stumbled upon it now. The problem ist that static constructors are called "before everything else" as well. I did work on something related and quickly tested it. At least arm-eabi-gcc puts C++ constructor calls and function defined with __attribute__((constructor)) both in the .init_array section. On a per-module basis, functions defined with __attribute__((constructor)) seem to come first, but the linked output has all of them intermixed.