# Thread-safe init of read-only global data

Tags: c, multithreading, initialization, global-variables

Let's imagine that I'm writing a library that has a reasonably large amount of read-only global data that needs to be initialized before the library can be used. For example, perhaps the global data be lookup tables for various parts of the application logic that won't change during the lifetime of the program.

Now I have a few ways to initialize this data:

1. I may require that the user call some kind of `init()` function before the library is used.
2. I may lazily construct the data the first time a function is called on my library.
3. I may include the data in a initializer statement in the source, such that variables are statically initialized to their final value.

Now if my data is read-only *and should be the same for every environment the library runs in*, then (3) is fairly appealing. Even in that case it has some downsides: if the data is very large (but easy to generate procedurally) the size of bloat up a lot (e.g., a library with 50K of code but 8MB of lookup tables would end up around 8050K). Similarly, the source itself may be very large, or the build system needs to handle the generation of the source at compile time.

The main reason you might not able to use (3) is that the tables might be fixed (read-only), but require generation at runtime because they embed some information about the environment (e.g., the value of an environment variable, I configuration setting read from a file, information about the machine architecture, whatever). This data can't be embedded in the source since depends on the runtime environment.

So we have methods (1) and (2) at least - but I can't see how to make these thread-safe in a simple way. The rest of the library can be thread-safe simply by not mutating any global state - just like the vast majority of C functions can be written in a thread-safe way w/o any explicit use of threading primitives.

I can't figure out a similar alternative for this global init, however:

(1) Is undesirable because we prefer not to require the user to call this method, and in any case it simply moves the problem up to the calling code: the calling code then needs to organize to call this `init()` method exactly once across all threads using the library, and before any thread uses the library.

(2) Fails since concurrent calls to the library might do a double init.

In C++ you can just initialize globals with a method call, like `int data[] = loadData()`. Is there any equivalent in C? Or am I stuck using threading primitives (which vary by platform, e.g., `pthread_once`, `call_once` and whatever Windows has) just to get my thread-safe init?

Comment: I would prefer (1), but with init() returning a void* 'context' for use in subsequent calls.  Makes it thread-safe or, at least, not intrinsically thread-unsafe;)  Obviously, any thread needing to use the lib would have to call init() to get its very own context.

Comment: Sure, I have something similar to a "context", but how does that work under the covers? Clearly I don't want to copy the shared read-only global state for each context (imagine several MB of lookup tables in a context that is otherwise < 100 bytes, where a heavy user of the library might create 1000s of contexts). So the context need to maintain a pointer to the shared read-only tables, but then the creation of these tables has the raciness issue. @ThingyWotsit

Comment: LOL, I'm tempted to say 'write an init() 'extern C' caller in C++ just to get access to a static initializer that runs before main().  I'm sure to get panned for suggesting that, however..

Comment: You must worry about thread-safety because your code is modifying global variables (dynamically loading information modifies the global variables, even if they never subsequently change), and you must use some method to ensure that you do not get concurrent initialization of the data. You can use any suitable method — a mutex, an 'execute only once' function, … If there's initialization that's needed anyway, I'd recommend using the `init` function approach. If there's no need for initialization, then the 'initialize when first called' approach also works. Synchronization is roughly the same.

Comment: Yes, I am modifying them, but exactly once, which can be prior to subsequent code running. For non-zero static initialization you also have a modify once type scenario (although depending on the platform it may or may not actually have a zero-init then non-zero init phases) - but that introduces no thread-safety issue. So it isn't obvious that modify once necessarily needs heavyweight exclusion (one can dream, right?). @JonathanLeffler

Comment: It depends on whether you're prepared to require a call to the initialization function to occur before any threads are spawned.  If the library can be first used when there are multiple threads running, you have to take the same care over the 'initialize once' access as you would with 'modify frequently' — you have to ensure that access is serialized.  Anything else is not thread-safe.  Note that restrictions on when the library functions are first called render the library less useful.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - indeed, and that's I want to avoid any unnecessary restrictions on the calling code. I don't want an `init()` method at all really, you should just be able to call into the library after linking with it (of course, the init can exist, but hidden within the library logic). In C++ it's possible with initializer functions so I guess is there is magic in the runtime environment that ensures this code gets called before the library is used (e.g., by the dynamic linker for a dll or .so) - just wondering if I can access that magic from C.

Comment: So, you're going to need some sort of 'heavyweight' synchronization mechanism to ensure that the initialization is done once.  A mutex might be sufficient (or a mutex plus a condition), but a 'call once' function might be cleaner.  Since any thread-aware code has to adapt to different thread libraries, you aren't any worse off than you were before — even if the situation is not optimal from your viewpoint.

Comment: I remember seeing how such 'magic' was implemented by a compiler (although it was for an experimental runtime environment).  Every call to a method of a class that required static initialization on first use, was pointing to a proxy function that checked if the static initializer had run, if not, a mutex was entered, next, the initalizer was called, next the code was patched to remove the proxy calls and point the code to the real methods, then the mutex was released, finally the proxy chain-called the real method. This way there was no further overhead checking if initialization was required.

Comment: Rectifying my post, I think that the check to see if the initializer had run should have been made AFTER acquiring the mutex, to account for race conditions.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - that's my point: other than this one requirement, this code is thread-safe without being thread-aware. I.e., it is mostly straightforward to write thread-safe code in standard C: you just have to ensure you don't mutate global state (which sometimes means a slightly different API, see all the various `_r` functions added to update some C routines). So it's a share that I have to add in thread-awareness just to initialize some global data.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any platform-independent way of initializing a library in a thread-safe manner.  That's not surprising since there's no platform-independent threading model in C.

So your solution is going to be platform-specific.

@ThingyWotsit mentions in the comments using C++ to initialize your library, and that will be thread-safe.  But it may very well lock you into a specific C++ run-time, so it may not be a useful solution for your C shared object/library.  You may not be willing or able to add a dependency on C++ and you may especially not be willing or able to be locked into a specific C++ run-time.

For GCC, [you can use the `__attribute((constructor))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.1/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) to have your iniitaliziation function called when the shared object is loaded:

> ```
> constructor
> destructor
> constructor (priority)
> destructor (priority)
> ```
>
> The constructor attribute causes the function to be called automatically before execution enters main ().
>   Similarly, the destructor attribute causes the function to be called
>   automatically after main () has completed or exit () has been called.
>   Functions with these attributes are useful for initializing data that
>   will be used implicitly during the execution of the program.
>
> You may provide an optional integer priority to control the order in
>   which constructor and destructor functions are run. A constructor with
>   a smaller priority number runs before a constructor with a larger
>   priority number; the opposite relationship holds for destructors. So,
>   if you have a constructor that allocates a resource and a destructor
>   that deallocates the same resource, both functions typically have the
>   same priority. The priorities for constructor and destructor functions
>   are the same as those specified for namespace-scope C++ objects (see
>   C++ Attributes).

For example:

```
static __attribute__((constructor)) void my_lib_init_func( void )
{
    ...
}
```

Your code will run before `main()` is called.

If your library is dynamically loaded (explicit call to `dlopen()`, for exmaple), your init function will be called when your library is loaded, and your library won't be considered loaded until it returns.

Other compilers provide the functionally-identical `#pragma init()`:

```
#pragma init(my_lib_init_func)
static void my_lib_init_func( void )
{
    ...
}
```

See [#pragma init and #pragma fini using gcc compiler on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459859/pragma-init-and-pragma-fini-using-gcc-compiler-on-linux)

For Windows?  The Windows C++ run-time is pretty stable and ubiquitous.  I'd just use a C++ solution on Windows, especially if you're compiling with MSVC. (But see the comments...)

Comment: Thanks. Am to understand the `C++` runtime is not stable and ubiquitous on other platforms such as Linux? Seems hard to believe...

Comment: @SODIMM  C++ runtime libraries are stable, but there are more than one for just about every platform, and they usually don't play well together.  For example, if you use the [GNU C++ runtime](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Libstdc++) for a Linux distribution, none of the users of your library could use the [Apache C++ runtime](http://stdcxx.apache.org/). It's not needed for a C library. On Windows you're a lot less likely to see users of GNU or Apache or any other non-Microsoft C++ runtime, and if you're already compiling your code  on Windows with MSVC you're already likely tied to the MS runtime.

Comment: Thanks, although FWIW I think on Linux the platform/gcc libc and libc++ are pretty much the equivalent of the MS runtimes in ubiquity and compatibility. I just haven't heard of people complaining that they are going to use the Apache runtime or whatever (and they can recompile it themselves if they want to). Plus don't the MSVC runtimes have that annoying thing where you have to ship the redistributable package or force your users to install it in case they don't have it? Seems worse than Linux libc++ in that respect...

Comment: @SODIMM While glibc++ in general is ubiquitous on Linux, specific versions aren't.  And you may be right about the MS C++ runtime connection to the redistributable package - the only MS binaries I've had experience with distributing were full executables to corporate-controlled machines that I knew were identical to my development hosts. That's different from a DLL.  I might have to rethink my recommendation for a C++ solution on MS...

Comment: Yes, there are many versions of the C++ libraries on Linux, but they are both carefully versioned and in general they are made to be backwards compatible, and (to a limited extend) so it usually "works". In particular, the careful versioning avoids (in principle) the situation where things break because the implementation changes (you'd just get a loader error if there is no compatible version), the effort to keep things compatible means there is a large window of libraries you can actually use (and many can be installed side-by-side).

Comment: ... and while it's up to each distribution exactly how many versions (how far back in time) C++ runtimes they install, it's a fairly simple matter to install an older one and then it works for all applications (I've had to do it when I installed an old application). Finally, if you use any kind of package manager, this is all invisible to the end user anyway (the right C++ library will be pulled in if not already installed).

Answer (score 0):

Option 3 is always preferable when possible. Your reasoning about the cons is wrong. If you have an 8MB constant table in the executable file, it's directly mapped and shared by all instances of the program or users of the shared library on any remotely modern operating system. If you generate it at runtime, each process will have its own copy of the table.

When option 3 is not available you must use `pthread_once` or equivalent or implement your own version of the same (much less efficiently) using a lock. There is little reason to use weird OS-specific replacements for it; all major platforms either support POSIX threads API natively or have existing libraries which provide it on top of the platform's low-level primitives.

Comment: Thanks R. I'm not following the part where you say "Your reasoning about the const is wrong". To which reasoning are you referring?

Comment: If you mean about the bloat of the binary, I don't see where it is wrong. Yes, each process would have its own table, so if you had several processes all generating all the tables it would use more memory, of course (unless you organized to also use shared memory for the dynamically generated tables). That doesn't change the fact that it may bloat the library from 50K to 8050K! Neither scenario dominates the other...

Comment: Furthermore, 8 MB is an example. There could be perhaps be 100 MB of LUTs or more at some point, and it seems unrealistic to embed them all int the binary (that's the total LUT load, at runtime many fewer may be generated since the LUT generation may depend on the usage).

Comment: Regardless of size it's still better. Only pages actually hit are loaded. Disk is cheap, ram is expensive.

Comment: Honestly, if you believe it isn't a tradeoff, I don't think we have much more to discuss here (FWIW, most LUTs in high performance libraries are dynamically generated despite your "it's always better, without qualification" claim. If you told me that a mobile app will load 15 ms faster if you increase the download and on-disk size by 100 MB, you've probably lost your job (if you had one) - and this from a guy whose profile links to [a comparison](http://www.etalabs.net/compare_libcs.html) of libc implementations which headlines the binary size. WTF?